# Laradock PhpStorm Xdebug - Specified URL is not reachable, caused by:'Request failed with status code 404'

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, laradock

I want to use Xdebug for remote server on my local machine. I have started Xdebug on php-fpm container.

[image]

Here is my `php-fpm\xdebug.ini` file (same as `workspace\xdebug.ini`)

```ini
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_port=9009
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.cli_color=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="~/xdebug/phpstorm/tmp/profiling"

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9009
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

In PhpStorm, I've created new server like this:

[image]

DBGp Proxy:

[image]

and Xdebug port:

[image]

I am able to run my project on browser by going `http://localhost`

However, I can't pass validate in PhpStorm debug configuration

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: IMO most likely will be the deployment settings (or how it maps the local to remote): PhpStorm tries to put it's validation script into the website root but Laravel web-accessible folder is `PROJECT_ROOT/public/` (a subfolder). You can check the webserver log to see what URL/file gets called that returns that 404 response.

Comment: *"DBGp Proxy:"* You are NOT using DBGProxy (requires separate Proxy software on server side to be installed and configure) and you simply do not need it here.

Comment: Also: please check other (most recent) entries for `Laradoc` & `PhpStorm` tags -- they can give you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laradock+phpstorm

Comment: Also, enable XDebugging logs & check what they're saying: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs